# reading files: XLConnect modifies my number

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am reading an excel spreadsheet with the following command

```
models <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook(bla.xlsx)
models <- readWorksheet(models,sheet1,check.names=F)
```

however I noticed that R modifies my number. For example in Excel: 
1.011379571

and in R
1.011379570999999977

did anyone had this issue. I know it's very small issues but I really need 100% precision

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with numerical precision an numeric representation. Excel chooses to print the value up to ~10 digits, while the value in R is printed up to ~16 digits. Most likely, the underlying values between the two values are the same, and 100% precision is impossible. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) for more details.

Comment: and R could only show the added digits if they were there in excel.